# Nestjs testing module not found

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I created a simple REST API using Mongdoose with Nestjs. I have in total 2 tests and they are failing.
The test output:

> FAIL  src/app/auth/auth.service.spec.ts
>     ● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module '@shared/errors' from 'auth.service.ts'

   5 | 
   6 | import { AppLogger } from '../logger/logger';
>  7 | import { Errors } from '@shared/errors';
     | ^
   8 | import { ILoginDto } from './dto/login.dto';
   9 | import { ITokenDto } from './dto/auth.dto';
  10 | import { IUser } from '@user/document/user.doc';

  at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (auth/auth.service.ts:7:1)
```

FAIL  src/app/user/user.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module '@shared/errors' from 'user.service.ts'

  1 | import { BadRequestException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
  2 | import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
> 3 | import { Errors } from '@shared/errors';
    | ^
  4 | import { createMultipleRandom } from '@shared/utils';
  5 | import { Model } from 'mongoose';
  6 | import { AppLogger } from '../logger/logger';

  at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (user/user.service.ts:3:1)
```

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.751s
Ran all test suites.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@auth/*": ["src/app/auth/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@logger/*": ["src/app/logger/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
      "@user/*": ["src/app/user/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

auth.service.spec.ts:

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [AuthService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

In @shared/errors.ts I just export a constant variable. Since it is not a module, how should I import this in a test ? How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using typescript's path mapping, you need to also update your jest config with the mapped paths as well. Your jest config needs to have the following added:

```js
{
  ...
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@Shared/(.)*$": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1"
  }
}
```

Assuming that your `<rootDir>` is set to be `.` and not `./src`. You can [find more info on it here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#paths-mapping).

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me :) I am trying now to test services, which use Mongoose model, do you also have some tips for this ? I think that this https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#testing will help me

Comment: You'll need a mock model to manage that. You can [see some examples here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: I mocked the model like in the examples, but I have now another problem. It says, that 'DatabaseConnection' is not available in the MongooseModule context. Since I do mock, why should I need a connection though ?

Comment: That would lead me to believe that you still have a database connection in use in your code somewhere. Without seeing what's happening, it can't easily be answered. Sounds like some model it's fully mocked, but again, can't say for sure

Comment: I found the problem. Inside "AuthService" I injected "UserService", which uses the MongooseModule.forFeature(...). So the MongooseModule was missing in the test file. After I imported the module, where the  MondooseModule.forRoot(..) was imported, it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Link no longer works. new link [here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping)

Comment: In cases where the <rootDir> is set to "rootDir": "src", you can use this;
 "^@Shared/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1"

Answer (score 10):

If you're coming from google then this can also happen if VSCode autocompletes your imports as `src/xyz/abc/service.ts` instead of `../xyz/abc/service.ts`.

When running tests the test code won't be able to locate the correct service(s) at run-time. It needs fully relative paths without an absolute `'src/'` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! any way to change this behaviour in VSCode?

Comment: I don't use VSCode unfortunately it's far inferior to webstorm and as such I have never had this issue in webstorm. I filed this answer on behalf of a coworker who uses VSCode and had this issue.

Comment: I managed to change these settings: `JavaScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier` and `TypeScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier` to `relative`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed configurations for jest-path-resolving problem.

The defined keys inside the moduleNameMapper will be replaced with their values.

For example, when jest sees '@resources', it will replace it with 'src/resources'

(Using index file helps a lot)

Jest configuration in the package.json

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@resources": "<rootDir>/resources",
      "@shared": "<rootDir>/shared",
      "@email": "<rootDir>/email",
      "@auth": "<rootDir>/auth",
      "@config": "<rootDir>/config",
      "@database": "<rootDir>/database"
    },
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

Typescript configuration

```
 "paths": {
      "@resources/*": ["src/resources/*"],
      "@resources": ["src/resources"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/shared/*"],
      "@shared": ["src/shared"],
      "@email/*": ["src/email/*"],
      "@email": ["src/email"]
    }
```